# Angular momentum about com

Tags: angular-momentum, angular-velocity

I was thinking that what could possibly be the **angular momentum about centre of mass of a rod** of **mass M** and **length L** hinged about it's one end and rotating with **angular velocity W**....unable to think help!

Comment: *"angular momentum about centre of mass "* while *"hinged about it's one end"*?

Comment: As Steeven points out, your question is contradictory. Have you done an internet search for moment of inertia J of rod? Angular momentum is $L=J\omega$.

Comment: but it would have angular momentum that may or may not be 0 about any point in space so how is it contradictory ..?

Answer (score 2):

A rod rotating with $\vec{\omega}$ is hinged on one side at point *A*. The center of mass is at point *C*.

1. The velocity of the center of mass is $\vec{v}_C = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_{AC}$
2. The linear momentum of the rod is $\vec{p} = m \vec{v}_C$
3. The angular momentum about the com is $\vec{L}_C = {\rm I}_C \vec{\omega}$
4. The angular momentum about the pin is $\vec{L}_A = \vec{L}_C + \vec{r}_{AC} \times \vec{p}$
5. The MMOI about the pin is found from the angular momentum about the pin $$\vec{L}_A = {\rm I}_C \vec{\omega} + m \vec{r}_{AC} \times \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_{AC} = {\rm I}_A \vec{\omega}$$

Does this help you think?

Comment: but since it is performing pure rotation about pin it's angular momentum = (I(about axis through pin ) x W)

Comment: The MMOI through the pin is found by 4) above.